# Split vector to unique and duplicates c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, split, unique

My goal is to split a vector into **two parts**: with unique values and with duplicates.

For example I have **sorted** `vector myVec=(1,1,3,4,4,7,7,8,9,9)` which should be split into `myVecDuplicates=(1,7,4,9)` and `myVecUnique=(1,4,7,9,3,8).` So myVecDuplicates contains all values that have duplicates while myVecUnique contains all values but in a single embodiment.

The order does not matter. My idea was to use unique as it splits a vector into two parts. But I have a problem running my code.

```
vector<int> myVec(8)={1,1,3,4,4,7,8,9};
vector<int>::iterator firstDuplicate=unique(myVec.begin(),myVec.end());
vector<int> myVecDuplicate=myVec(firstDuplicate,myVec.end());\\here error accures that says ' no match for call to '(std::vector<int>) (std::vector<int>::iterator&, std::vector<int>::iterator)'
vector<int> myVecUnique=myVec(myVec.begin()+firstDuplicate-1,myVec.end());
```

After running this code I get an error that says (2nd line) 'no match for call to '(std::vector) (std::vector::iterator&, std::vector::iterator)'

Please help me to understand the source of error or maybe suggest some more elegant and fast way to solve my problem (without hash tables)!

Comment: you need to std::sort the vector before using std::unique. getting the duplicates is a bit more complex.

Comment: The vector I run code for is sorted

Comment: unique doesnt erase all duplicates, but only consecutive ones. Either you have to sort before or do it differently

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: vector<int> myVecDuplicate(firstDuplicate,myVec.end()); however, this does not solve your problem :)

Comment: Is this an assignment? If not, using a set/multiset instead of a vector might make things easier.

Comment: Yes it does not, but it gives me an array of values that have duplicates in myVec so then getting unique from myVecDuplicate will solve

Comment: I don't understand your example. Why are `7` and `9` in both containers?

Comment: The values that have duplicates appear in both containers while those that have non only in unique container

Comment: Why is `myVecDuplicates=(1,7,4,9)`?  Shouldn't it be `myVecDuplicates=(1,4)`

Comment: That you  NathanOliver I have eddited

Comment: Check the document and example at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/

Comment: @Bogdan - if `myVec=(1,2,2,3,3,3,3)` should `myVecDuplicates` become `(2,3)` or `(2,3,3,3)`?

Comment: hailinzeng I have already read this link to understand unique return value.  Gavin Lock myVecDuplicates=(2,3)

Comment: The boring approach would be to use an intermediate `std::map<number, count>`, build that up from your input, then iterate over this to create two containers for the single and multiple occurrences. The interesting way would be to understand how quicksort works, and base a solution on a modified version of that.

Comment: Bathsheba thank you for idea so I will try it later and maybe post my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh..Too many edits  in your question for anyone's liking. Just keep it simple by using **map**.

In C++, *map* comes really handy in storing the **unique + sorted + respective_count** values.

```
map<int, int> m;
for(auto &t : myVec){
    m[t]++;
}
vector<int> myVecDuplicate, myVecUnique;
for(map<int, int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++){
    if(it->second > 1) myVecDuplicate.push_back(it->first);
    myVecUnique.push_back(it->first);
}
```

**Edit:**

> maybe suggest some more elegant and fast way to solve my problem  (without hash tables)!

1. Sort the vector
2. Traverse through the sorted vector,

and do

```
  if (current_value == previous_value){
    if(previous_value != previous_previous_value)
     myVecDuplicate.push_back(current_value);
  }
  else{
      myVecUnique.push_back(current_value);
  }
```

To start, initialize previous_value = current_value - 1
and previous_previous_value as current_value - 2.

Comment: Please don't discourage a user from improving their question.

Comment: @Bathsheba Unless the question is edited in such a fashion that it makes existing answers invalid.

Comment: @GillBates: Absolutely.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But I am still strongly would like to have some solution using unique as I am also interesting how to use its return value.

Comment: @Bogdan  When you use `unique` you often use it with `erase` so it actually removes the duplicates from the vector.

Comment: This will turn your `myVec` into `myVecUnique` : `sort(myVec.begin(),myVec.end());
 std::vector<int>::iterator it = unique(myVec.begin(),myVec.end());
 myVec.resize( std::distance(myVec.begin(),it) );`. Note that you need to **sort->unique->resize** the vector.

Answer (score 1):

While this may be frowned upon (for not using standard algorithms and such), I would write some simple solution like this:

```
vector<int> myVec = {1,1,3,4,4,7,8,9};
unordered_set<int> duplicates;
unordered_set<int> unique;

for(int & v : myVec)
{
    if(unique.count(v) > 0)
        duplicates.insert(v);
    else
        unique.insert(v);
}
```

Comment: **Frowning intensifies**

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` has a constructor that accepts 2 iterators for range [first,second[ You cannot call constructor for existing object - it is already created, so your code

```
myVec(firstDuplicate,myVec.end());
```

actually tries to use `myVec` as a functor, but `std::vector` does not have `operator()` hence the error.

you have 2 ways, pass 2 iterators to  constructor directly:

```
vector<int> myVecDuplicate(firstDuplicate,myVec.end());
```

or use copy initialization with temporary vector:

```
vector<int> myVecDuplicate = vector<int>(firstDuplicate,myVec.end());
```

Same for the second vector:

```
 vector<int> myVecUnique(myVec.begin(),firstDuplicate);
```

as pointed by Logman `std::unique` does not seem to guarantee value of duplicates, so working solution can use `std::set` instead (and you would not have to presort source vector):

```
std::set<int> iset;
vector<int> myVecUnique, myVecDuplicate;
for( auto val : myVec )
    ( iset.insert( val ).second ? myVecUnique : myVecDuplicate ).push_back( val );
```

Comment: It is exactly what I need. Thank you very much! But I will mark saurav answer as the best as it mostly satisfies formal side of the question.

Comment: @Bogdan Working of this solution is heavily dependent on unique implementation as `myVec` after `firstDuplicate` iterator contains unspecified data. Ex. v=={1,2,2,3}, unique(v), v=={1,2,3,3} and not expected v=={1,2,3,2}

Answer (score 1):

O(n) complexity solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVec = {1,1,3,4,4,7,7,8,9,9};
    std::vector<int> myVecDuplicatec;
    std::vector<int> myVecUnique;

    for(int &x : myVec)
    {
        if(myVecUnique.size() == 0 || myVecUnique.back() != x)
            myVecUnique.push_back(x);
        else
            myVecDuplicatec.push_back(x);
    }

    std::cout << "V = ";
    for(int &x : myVec)
    {
        std::cout << x << ",";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "U = ";
    for(int &x : myVecUnique)
    {
        std::cout << x << ",";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "D = ";
    for(int &x : myVecDuplicatec)
    {
        std::cout << x << ",";
    }

}
```

[cpp.sh/4i45x](http://cpp.sh/4i45x)